# python setup.py to create wheel file to include files from another directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools

The current setup.py creates 2 different whl files using a for loop, which we are able to use in AWS Glue and we are able to configure using additional-python-modules.

But in AWS EMR, we cannot use multiple whl files (confirmed by AWS Support team) for --py-files, and for this reason, I am trying to bundle all files to one whl file.

My folder structure is as follows, and due to client restrictions, I cannot change the setup.py location, since this is common code for some AWS Services.

```
main_dir
|
|
|_________>sub_dir_1
|       test1.py
|       test2.py
|
|_________>sub_dir_2
|   |
|   |_________>__init__.py
|          file1.py
|          file2.py
|          setup.py
|
|_________>tests         
|
|_________>sub_dir_3
|
|_________>others
```

I have my setup.py available in sub_dir_2, and I want the wheel file to include sub_dir_1 also?  I tried the following but am getting errors, appreciate any help please.

```
from setuptools import find_packages, setup

setup(
    name="whl_test",
    version="1.0",
    description="Wheel file",
    author="MyName",
    packages=(find_packages(
        where="main_dir",
        include=["sub_dir_1", "sub_dir_2"],
        exclude=["*.tests","*.sub_dir_3","*.others"])),
    install_requires=[],
    namespace_packages=["test"],
)
```

I need this because, test1, test2 are considered some helper util files, and I need to reference from file1, file2, etc.  Thanks. Am new to setuptools,wheel packaging,etc. please.

Comment: can you share the errors you got?

Comment: sorry, i dont have the error message, since it was on a AWS Workspace, and i have cleared it.  I think, it was error saying path not found for ./sub_dir_1, since setup.py is in sub_dir_2.  Hope this helps.  Thanks

Comment: Any restriction to having the setup file in the main_dir? It would solve your issue.

Comment: yes, I have mentioned in my 2nd paragraph.  it would be simple if i can have setup one level above, yes.

Comment: Sorry, I missed it. I cannot reproduce the error, I tried to redo a similar setup but didn't get any error. Only difference I see now is that I put an `__init__.py` in both the `main_dir` and the `sub_dir1` but I'm not sure that's the difference. My initial thought was just to use `where: "../main_dir"` but both that and your setup file where able to build the wheel locally.